# MultiJob should not start when other MultiJob is running

Tags: git, jenkins, build

I'm using the plugin http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/ to create my jobs for feature-branches. Generating these jobs works great but I'm running into a problem when performing my builds.

My template job is scheduled to check SCM(Git) every 15 minutes. When generating the feature-branch jobs they'll be triggered because they're all new. The problem is that these jobs are all MultiJob jobs and this causes my executors to be all busy and not making place to start jobs inside the MultiJob.

> For example: 
>   MultiJob 1 - running 
>   MultiJob 2 - running

MultiJob 1 needs to start InsideJob 1 (one of the jobs inside MultiJob 1) but as MultiJob 2 already started running there is no place anymore for InsideJob 1.

So in some way I would like to be able to say 'do not start a MultiJob when there is still another MultiJob running'. As the job names are generated and using the number/name of the feature-branch I can't specify a name where the other job should wait for.

Does anyone have a way to prevent the 2nd job from start running. Increasing the node's executors will just make MultiJob 3 start and so on so this isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by using the Build Blocker Plugin . https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin . I set the plugin to block all jobs that have the same prefix as my generated jobs and so only 1 MultiJob is executed at the time.